# Can you write stubs/mocks/doubles for methods inside of a method call?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

My method looks like:

```
def some_method(....)

  user = User.where("....").first

  if !user.nil?

     if ..
         user.delete
     elsif
         user.update_attributes(...)

  else
     new_user = User.new(...)
     new_user.save!
  end

end
```

As you can see both user and new_user are instantiated inside this method.

Is it possible to stub and mock (expectations) for these objects when I am testing the method?

I am trying this:

```
it "should ...." do

  d = double("user double")
  d.should_receive(:save!).once

  res = User.some_method(....)

end
```

But I get an error saying expected 1 time and received 0 times.

Am I doing this right? (obviously not, is this possible to test for since I can't pass these stubs/mocks to the method being tested)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
user_double = double("user")
User.should_receive(:where).and_return(user_double)
user_double.should_receive(:delete)
```

Comment: I am doing that (see above) and still getting expected 1 times, received 0 times failure/error. for User.should_receive(:where).once

Comment: Can you post the actual code you're using. Your code above doesn't contain User.should_receive(:where).